# Holomorphic function restricted to curves

Tags: complex-analysis

> Supppose $F:B_{r}(z_0) \to \mathbb{C}$ holomorphic with $F(z_0) = F'(z_0) = 0$ and $F''(z_0) \neq 0$. Show that there exist two curves $\gamma_1, \gamma_2: [0, 1] \to B_{r}(z_0)$ such that:
>
> i) $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ pass through $z_0$ and are orthogonal at $z_0$;
>
> ii) $F$ restricted to $\gamma_1$ is real with minimum at $z_0$;
>
> iii) $F$ restricted to $\gamma_2$ is real with maximum at $z_0$.
>
> [Hint: Write $F(z) = (g(z))^2$ for $z$ near $z_0$, and consider the mapping $z \to g(z)$ and its inverse.]

I have a few questions about this problem. First, I thought that in order to define $g$ we would have to talk about the logarithm of $F$, but how can we do that if $F(z_0)=0$? Second, how do we know $g$ has an inverse? Third, how do all that help me with the problem?

My first attempt without using the hint was to consider the set $\{(x, y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid v(x, y)=0\}$, where $v=\text{Im}(F)$, but since I don't know much about $F$, I feel totally stuck.

Comment: You can start this problem "in the middle". Suppose you already know that $F(z) = (g(z))^2$, what would$g(z_0)$ and $g'(z_0)$ have to be? Would $g$ have a local inverse? And how would you find the two curves?

Comment: And an even simpler start. What is the simplest case for such a function $F$? What is $g$ in this case? What are the two curves in this case? What is the behavior of $g$ on these curves?

Comment: for your question about $\log F(z)$, show that $\log \frac{F(z)}{z^2}$ is holomorphic on a disk around $z=0$, so that $g(z) = z \exp(\frac12\log \frac{F(z)}{z^2})$